# Chrome Browser Version 42.0.2311.152 m (64-bit) - does not allow to view pdf on browser in protractor automated test

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, angularjs-e2e, browser-automation, protractor-net

new version Chrome browser does not includes -Mine type - application/pdf(when run through protractor), which would allow me to view pdf on browser and test the url through protractor, but its automatically download and close the tab. If you go through manually open the chrome and click link it opens the pdf in next tab and dont download automatically.

**Manually run chrome has following extension::**

```
Chrome PDF Viewer (2 files)
Name:   Chrome PDF Viewer
Version:    
**Location: chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/
Type:   BROWSER PLUGIN
    Disable
MIME types: 
MIME type   Description File extensions
application/pdf     
.pdf**
Name:   Chrome PDF Viewer
Description:    Portable Document Format
Version:    
Location:   internal-pdf-viewer
Type:   PPAPI (out-of-process)
    Disable
MIME types: 
MIME type   Description File extensions
application/x-google-chrome-pdf Portable Document Format    
.pdf
Disable   Always allowed to run
```

**Chrome Automation Extension - Run by Protractor**
(MIME type - application/pdf extension is missing here which allow the browser to view pdf on browser on the chrome automation extension run by direct connect browser by protractor)

```
Chrome PDF Viewer
Portable Document Format
Name:   Chrome PDF Viewer
Description:    Portable Document Format
Version:    
Location:   internal-pdf-viewer
Type:   PPAPI (out-of-process)
    Disable
MIME types: 
MIME type   Description File extensions
application/x-google-chrome-pdf Portable Document Format    
.pdf
Disable   Always allowed to run
```

**There is a similar issue on chrome but no solution yet** : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/A3XrBbHD80U

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you don't care about the warning message when the test are running then this should work:

```
"desiredCapabilities": {
    "chromeOptions": {
      "excludeSwitches": [ "test-type" ]
    }
  }
```